# Change Image Sequences on Different Slides

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've modified this parallax website-template that is separated into different sections and slides. On each slide I want a fixed positioned image sequence to animate based on its scroll position on each slide. Since every frame is relative to the scrollTop() value, an animation of 91 images is over pretty quickly. As such I want it to show a frame for every 4 or 5 pixel from scrollTop(). How do I do this?

HTML:

```
<body>
    <main>
    <!-- SECTIONS -->
        <section id="slide-1" class="homeSlideTall">
            <div class="bcg" data-center="background-position: 50% 0px;" data-bottom-top="background-position: 50% 100px;" data-top-bottom="background-position: 50% -200px;" data-anchor-target="#slide-1">
                <div class="hsContent" data-start="opacity: 1; top: 206px;" data-100-bottom="opacity: 1;top: 206px; left: 0px; width: 100%;" data-top-bottom="opacity: 0; top: -550" data-anchor-target="#slide-1">
                    <div class="boxScroll img" > 
                        <img src="/img/model/0.png" width="960" height="540" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="boxScroll" > 
                        <h2>Carried Away</h2>
                        Product-text
                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>
        </section>

        <section id="slide-3" class="homeSlideTall">
            <div class="bcg" data-center="background-position: 50% 0px;" data-bottom-top="background-position: 50% 10px;" data-top-bottom="background-position: 50% -10px;" data-anchor-target="#slide-3">
                <div class="hsContent" data-bottom-top="opacity: 0; top: 1000px" data-top="opacity: 1;  top: 206px; width: 100%;" data-100-bottom="opacity: 1;  position: fixed; top: 206px; width: 100%;" data-top-bottom="opacity: 0; top: -550"   data-anchor-target="#slide-3">
                    <div class="boxScroll img" > 
                        <img src="/img/model/0.png" width="960" height="540" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="boxScroll" > 
                        <h2>Way</h2>
                        Product-text
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
    </main>
</body>
```

JQuery:

```
jQuery(window).on("scroll",function() {
    var n = $(window).scrollTop(),
    divOffset = $('#slide-1').offset().top,
    dist = (n - divOffset);
    if (dist <= 0) { var dist = 0; } // Check that value isn't smaller than   0
    if (dist >= 91) { var dist = 91; } // In case there aren't any more frames show the last one in the sequence
    jQuery("#slide-1 .boxScroll img").attr({src:"/img/model/"+dist+".png"});
});
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. I have created a jsFiddle for testing: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/z7m3zn87/ Please edit your post and include what you have tried and what errors you encounter.

Comment: Added in some output: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/z7m3zn87/1/ I am not sure what you're trying to accomplish, but it seems to be replacing the Image source as needed when the distance changes enough.

Comment: @Twisty Hi, thanks and thanks for your replies. I'm sorry if I were unclear. I managed to solve it when I found this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/qJhRz/3/

It works exactly as I wanted it. The following then made the scrollTop() "reset" to zero

newTop = $(this).scrollTop();
    divOffset = $('#slide-3').offset().top;
    dist = newTop - divOffset;
    
    
    frame  = Math.floor(dist / pixels);

Answer (score 0):

This was exactly what I was looking for:

http://jsfiddle.net/qJhRz/3/

```
var newTop = 0, 

// animate every 10 pixels
pixels = 10, 

// starting frame
frame = 0;

$(window).scroll(function(event) {

//position of the window
newTop = $(this).scrollTop();

// working out what frame to be on
frame  = Math.floor(newTop / pixels);

//frame is the number frame you should animate to
});
```

Thanks.